# What is wrong with my code (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, php, comparison-operators

I'am really frustrated with the result I'm getting in my code:

userOldPass         //from user input, user's old password

oldPass             //from database, user's old password

newPass             //from user input, user's new password

confirmNewPass      //from user input, user's new password confirmation

```
function checkpass(){

        if(userOldPass==oldPass) && (newPass==comfirmNewPass){
            alert('success');

        }else{
            alert('error');

        }

}
```

The problem is it always says 'error' even if the inputs are already all correct. I checked each variables' values via the alert function to see if there is some inequalities but everything is okay and still it alerts 'error'.

What could be the problem?

P.S. all the variables are in SHA1 hash. I used the CryptoJS.SHA1 function I found in the net.
I use the alert function to check each value from the variables and the results are right.

Comment: Are you getting password hash from database and passing it to JS?

Comment: yes sir. all values are correct but still it prints 'error'.

Comment: Don't do that.. It's worst idea ever!

Comment: okay can you elaborate it so i can get your point?

Comment: We're hashing passwords to make it harder to steal. Also we're implementing mechanisms that are blocking user after eg. 3 bad passwords entered. But when you're sending that hash to browser (JS) you're allowing infinite number of tries to break it. Don't treat it as unbreakable (especially that it's only SHA1).

Comment: okay, i understand. how can you implement it better?

Comment: Don't check old password in JS. It's task for PHP (or any other server-side language). New password check can be on client-side because it's entered by user in current request.

Comment: You'll probably get more eyes on this if you title it something more descriptive than "What is wrong with my code"...

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(userOldPass==oldPass) && (newPass==comfirmNewPass) // all should stay in ()
```

In this way:

```
if ((userOldPass==oldPass) && (newPass==comfirmNewPass))
```

Comment: i just did your suggestion sir, but still doesn't solve the problem

Comment: You can debug it with firebug and see if vars have the same value.

Comment: okay i'll try it. i used the alert function to see if variables have same value and they all have the same value.

Comment: try a trim, with jquery

Comment: I already solved my problem. though the variables have equal results in the function alert and there's seems to be no problem at all, I think it's semantically wrong, that's why it's still proceed in the else part even it should be true already.

The thing is the 'newPass==comfirmNewPass' doesn't match even they have equal results when I use alert function to show the values of each vars.

Comment: Anyway what I tried was I stored the value(from user's input) first to a new variable before doing the hash. Instead of storing it to a variable with the hash. 

I did this:

    var x = newPass.value;
    var y = confirmNewPass.value;
    var i = CryptoJS.SHA1(x);
    var j = CryptoJS.SHA1(y);


instead of:

    var x = CryptoJS.SHA1(newPass.value);
    var y = CryptoJS.SHA1(confirmNewPass.value);


And for some 'i-still-don't-know-reason', it worked. 

I still want to know what went wrong (what's the diff between the two blocks of code above) with my code although I get it to work already.

Comment: I need to comment my answer because i still can't post answer on my own problem because i still don't have 10 reputations.